# Subtract datetime.time objects stored in two separate lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, datetime, subtraction

I have two lists, each has an equal amount of objects in them at all times. They are `datetime.time` objects. e.g.

```
list1 = [ Dt_Obj_1, Dt_Obj_2]
list2 = [ Dt_Obj_3, Dt_Obj_4]
```

I always need to subtract in this format

```
list2[0] - list1[0] , list2[1] - list1[1], etc..
```

I need to return `timedelta` objects so I also have been trying to throw this in there:

```
datetime.combine(datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0), dt_obj2) - datetime.combine(datetime(1,1,1,0,0,0), dt_obj1)
```

with list comprehensions but I can't seem to find a way to put these things together in such a way to make it work. This  list can have up to a total of 7 `datetime.time()` objects stored in it, although I'm sure its trivial I thought I should mention it just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the lists, and [`datetime.datetime.combine()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) with [`datetime.date.min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.min):

```
import datetime
from functools import partial

comb = partial(datetime.datetime.combine, datetime.date.min)

result = [comb(t1) - comb(t2) for t1, t2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

I used [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here to make the list comprehension a little less verbose; calling `comb(argument)` is in essence the same as calling `datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.min, argument)`.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from functools import partial
>>> list1 = [datetime.time(10, 20), datetime.time(13, 14)]
>>> list2 = [datetime.time(2, 15), datetime.time(4, 21)]
>>> comb = partial(datetime.datetime.combine, datetime.date.min)
>>> [comb(t1) - comb(t2) for t1, t2 in zip(list1, list2)]
[datetime.timedelta(0, 29100), datetime.timedelta(0, 31980)]
```

Comment: I gave it a try im getting this error     `comb = partial(datetime.datetime.combine, datetime.date.min)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`

Comment: @DreamPie look at how I imported the module; you imported the objects *from* the module. Remove the module reference if you imported the types.

Comment: Woops, thank you. Now im getting this `comb = partial(datetime.combine, datetime.date.min)
AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'min'`

Comment: @DreamPie: again, you are referencing the wrong import there; you'd have to use `from datetime import date` and `date.min`.

Comment: Thanks , works great not to mention the `partial` module which i like better then the subtraction statement i had coded. Honestly, didn't even know it existed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import datetime

def seconds_since_midnight(time):
    return 3600*time.hour + 60*time.minute + time.second

def subtract_times(t1, t2):
    s1, s2 = map(seconds_since_midnight, [t1, t2])
    return datetime.timedelta(seconds = s1 - s2)

result = [subtract_times(t1, t2) for t1, t2 in zip(list2, list1)]
```

You could, of course, write all the code into a single function but I chose to do it this way.

Comment: you forgot `microseconds`. Also, in the future `nanoseconds` could be added (check `time.resolution`). You could construct `timedelta` directly (it accepts hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds keyword parameters). It is simpler to use `datetime.combine(datetime.date.min, time)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wonder why subtraction isn't supported by datetime.time objects.